# How can I pass a value from an input box (html file) to a javascript inject file (inject.js)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am wondering if there is a way to pass a value from a input box to another file (html to javascript) (Been stuck on this for couple days now and it's driving me insane) the problem with this is that it is a inject file and I think they don't work in the same fashion as other js files. So please if anyone has any idea please share.

What I want to do:

- Have an Input box in html file.

```
<input type="text" id="paste" placeholder = "paste text">
```

- Have whatever value input get sent to a inject.js file.

P.S this is for a google extension so bear that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can use a content script to monitor this iuput box , such as

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input',function(){...executer...})
```

And then every time the input text is changed, you can do something in executer

Comment: I've added the code an it gives me a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" error? any idea why?

Comment: This is just a example, maybe you should catch the specific DOM in the website and add eventlistener for it

Comment: That makes it a lot more complicated, but thank you will try.